# Cassandra Java Driver BoundStatement.setList works for set as well

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have a table userset

> create table IF NOT EXISTS userset (id int primary key, name set, phone set, emails list);

Now I am executing an insert statement through datastax java driver : cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar. Now I have a java.util.List of String say listString

```
List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
listString.add("NewName");
boundStatement.setList(1, listString);
```

Here boundStatement is an instance of com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement. On index 1 i am setting the value of name in userset.

Even though the backend type of name is set and I am using BoundStatement-> setList it still executes without any errors and inputs the value in the name correctly. Is this a functionality of BoundStatement in datastax driver.

Why doesn't it throw an error when I try to setList for a parameter which is a set in the backend server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can say it's a bug in the datastax driver.**

When you bind data with `boundStatement.setList` or `boundStatement.setSet` both method uses `lookupCodec` method to find the codec with the column type and don't validate the value.

But If you use `statement.bind` to bind data, it uses `findCodec` method to find the codec with column type and it's validate with the given value

```
if ((cqlType == null || cqlType.getName() == LIST) && value instanceof List) {
    //...........
}

if ((cqlType == null || cqlType.getName() == SET) && value instanceof Set) {
   //............
}
```